# Alert Dialog onClick visibility Edit Text add

Tags: android, extension-methods, visibility, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to use this code to set visibility for some of my edit text filed. my question is when I press the cancel button I would like the alert dialog return to his first form, before any change maked with visibility, how do I make it work ?
Also I would like to know how to make alert dialog small as it should be and extend it only when I press the button for visibility ?

```
AddC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        fromC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        txtName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtCompany.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v){
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: sure! you think something else ?

Comment: Is the code listed javascript?

Comment: @www139 Nope, it is Java. Code is related to Android